# PHP/SQL Delete button for each row

Tags: javascript, php, html

Ok, so I have a SELECT

```
$filme_cart = mysql_query("SELECT name, price FROM cart_test GROUP BY name");
```

and then I have a PHP code that looks like this:

```
<?php                                                                   
  while($film_cart=mysql_fetch_object($filme_cart))
  {                                                        
   echo "<tr>";                                                               
   echo "<td align='left'>";                                                                 
   echo $film_cart->name;                                                               
   echo "</td>";                                                            
   echo "<td class='cart-product-setting'>";                                                            
   echo $film_cart->price;                                                                
   echo "<a href='delete.php?delete_film=".$film_cart['id_film']."' class='remove-pro' rel='tooltip' data-title='Delete'><i class='icon-trash'></i></a></td>";                                                              
   echo "</tr>";
} 
?>
```

And my delete.php file looks like this:

```
<?php  
 include 'config.php';
 $delete_film=$_GET['id_film']; 
 $delete_cart = mysql_query("DELETE FROM cart_test WHERE id_film='$delete_film'");
?>
```

So, when I put that PHP code in my web page, my `<body>` disappears.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fix that formatting please.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty <body> "This disappears" </body> and <footer> This </footer>

Comment: @DigitalChris done. sorry

Comment: Great, another script I can hack as soon as it goes online! Thanks for giving me a fun moment, let me know when you'll put it online! //offtopic. To be serious; mysql -> mysqli, and don't use a $_GET directly in your query..

Comment: @JoranDenHouting I won't put it online :). It's for my college project.

Comment: If it's college, you should def update it or you won't get a good result ^^

Comment: @JoranDenHouting It's about SQL, not about web development. I just need to make a working application.

Comment: Still no excuse for not doing it the right way.. You'll learn many more by doing it right then doing it quick and sloppy

Comment: @JoranDenHouting So, how can I do it the right way?

Comment: @user3175636: try my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should use mysqli or pdo

You have missed 3 points:**
fix your query: 
**1)**      make sure you have selected all required fields.

```
$filme_cart = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cart_test GROUP BY name");
```

**2)** Try using: `mysql_fetch_assoc`

```
  <?php
    while($film_cart=mysql_fetch_assoc($filme_cart))
      {
      echo "<tr>";  
      echo "<td align='left'>";
      echo $film_cart['name'];
      echo "</td>";
      echo "<td class='cart-product-setting'>";
      echo $film_cart['price'];
      echo "<a href='delete.php?delete_film=".$film_cart['id_film']."' class='remove-pro' rel='tooltip' data-title='Delete'><i class='icon-trash'></i></a></td>";  
      echo "</tr>";
    } 
    ?>
```

And then : **3)** get value by `$_GET['delete_film']`

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$delete_film=$_GET['delete_film'];

$delete_cart = mysql_query("DELETE FROM cart_test WHERE id_film=$delete_film limit 1");

?>
```

Comment: @user3175636: it should be work. Can you you try this one?

Comment: it's working like this but now I have another issues with movie name and price.

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\localhost.web\temabd\index-2.php on line 122

Answer (score 1):

Your get parameter is called delete_film NOT id_film

So fix this line

```
$delete_film=$_GET['id_film'];
```

with this one

```
$delete_film=$_GET['delete_film'];
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not from here.

Comment: @user3175636 Print the var $delete_film, if it drops the data then maybe it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

1 - you need to select id_film from db 
    `mysql_query("SELECT id_film, name, price FROM cart_test GROUP BY name");`
2 - you are using mysql_fetch_assoc to fetch data, so you should echo data like:
    `echo $film_cart['name'];` 
not like:
    `echo $film_cart->name;`
3 - Your get parameter is called delete_film NOT id_film, so get value with:
    `$delete_film=$_GET['delete_film'];`
4 - mysql is deprecated in php 5.5, you should use pdo or mysqli
Good luck